# is it possible to dynamically create a function that has an ID in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, anonymous

I can use the following to create a function dynamically in javascript:

```
var MyClass = new Function("console.log('Hello World!');");
```

but when I do that, the ID will be set to 'anonymous'.
I would really like to give such a function an ID for debugging purposes; that's the id that's  shown when you console.log an instance of such a function(class).
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a `create` function like this:

```
var create = (function() { 
    var id = 0;

    return function(f) {
        return eval('(function id' + (id++) + (f + '').substr(8) + ')' );
    };
})();

var a = create(function() { alert(0); });
var b = create(function() { alert(1); });

alert(a); // function id0() { alert(0); }
alert(b); // function id1() { alert(1); }
a();      // 0
b();      // 1
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DKGgB/)

Comment: this might actually be useful. I need to get over the eval=evil feeling, but in this case it might make sense. (the classes have no constructor implementation anyway).

Comment: "eval is evil", but don't forget that also "new Function is evil", so I think you're ok with that.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: not possible, not even setting `function.name`. I honestly don't even see the point, since the `Function` constructor is for temporary, on-the-fly function created dynamically. So put them on viariables and you're done.

If you want them to have a name because you're creating a class, use the syntax

```
function MyClass(...) {
```

Notice that, anyway, some developer tools (like Chrome web inspector) are quite smart about it, and show `MyClass` even if you define it like this:

```
var MyClass = function() {...
```

Comment: The problem is that the classnames are not known at design time, so I cannot use the syntax you mention. I understand that you might not see the point from your perspective, but we are programming on a meta level so we have 1 class that is used hundreds of times. When you log it in the console, you will have to inspect it more thouroughly to know it's type (on meta level). That's not convenient.